# Unfortunately PHP file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch an url that is stored in the database. I am able to echo the url but when I try to use file_get_contents function to fetch the page, it says `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

PHP code to get the data from database

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Job, Link FROM primarydata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $job = $row["Job"];
    $link = $row["Link"];       
    echo $job;
    echo $link;
    $htmlcontent =  file_get_contents($link);
    echo $htmlcontent;
 }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am able to echo the URL but in next link it doesn't execute the `file_get_contents` function

Comment: Can you give us an example of a `$link` value that doesn't work? (you can obfuscate sensible informations with some `XXX` if there are some)

Comment: I have tried to echo `$link`, which is giving me the output as `https://somelink.com` Now I am trying the fetch the content of the URL

Comment: Better is to use curl as `allow_url_fopen` setting also might be disabled to preventing `file_get_contents()` to read from external sites..

Comment: If it works when you manually put the URL as you state in an answer comment, and not from the variable, it could be an encoding problem, which one I can't say from your example

Comment: So, fetching the URL fails. How is the rest of the code relevant for this problem? It is sometimes helpful to provide context, but I think in this case it is just distracting. See also Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example